# Multiline SQL String with sqlalchemy leads to "result object does not return rows"

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I have a SQL String in python/sqlalchemy - i have copied it here from debug:

```
DECLARE @AffectedRows TABLE (
                        Operation NVARCHAR(10),
                        [KEY] INT,
                        [change] DATETIME,
                        [ANNDAT] INT,
                        [ANNZEIT] INT,
                        [ENDDAT] INT,
                        [ENDZEIT] INT,
                        [RG] INT,
                        [DATAGRP] BIT
                    );
                    
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                    OUTPUT 'Inserted', inserted.[KEY], inserted.[change], inserted.[ANNDAT], inserted.[ANNZEIT], inserted.[ENDDAT], inserted.[ENDZEIT], inserted.[RG], inserted.[DATAGRP]
                    INTO @AffectedRows (Operation, [KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                    SELECT s.[KEY], s.[change], s.[ANNDAT], s.[ANNZEIT], s.[ENDDAT], s.[ENDZEIT], s.[RG], s.[DATAGRP]
                    FROM (
                        VALUES
                            ('53926', '2023-08-28 09:12:34', '20230822', 73000, 20230822, 121500, 0, 0),
                            -- Other values
                    ) AS s ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] t
                        WHERE t.[KEY] = s.[KEY]
                            AND t.[ANNDAT] = s.[ANNDAT]
                            AND t.[ANNZEIT] = s.[ANNZEIT]
                            AND t.[ENDDAT] = s.[ENDDAT]
                            AND t.[ENDZEIT] = s.[ENDZEIT]
                            AND t.[DATAGRP] = s.[DATAGRP]
                    );
                    
 UPDATE h
                    SET
                        h.[lastchange] = a.[change]
                    FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] h
                    JOIN @AffectedRows a ON h.[WFKKEY] = a.[KEY];
                    

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] ([WFKKEY], [lastchange], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                    SELECT
                        [KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP]
                    FROM @AffectedRows
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] h
                        WHERE h.[WFKKEY] = [KEY]
                            AND h.[ANNDAT] = [ANNDAT]
                            AND h.[ANNZEIT] = [ANNZEIT]
                            AND h.[ENDDAT] = [ENDDAT]
                            AND h.[ENDZEIT] = [ENDZEIT]
                            AND h.[DATAGRP] = [DATAGRP]
                    );
                    
 SELECT [WFKKEY]
  ,[SUBKEY]
  ,[DATAGRP]
  ,[RG]
  ,[lastchange]
  ,[ANNDAT]
  ,[ANNZEIT]
  ,[ENDDAT]
  ,[ENDZEIT]
  ,[LOCKJCL]
  FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] WHERE [ANNDAT] >= 20230822  AND [ENDDAT] >= 20230822 ;
```

When I run it with sqlalchemy in code, i get in console "`Error occurred during insert: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`" - when I run it in SSMS i get shown a full result set.
I am using `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and `SQLAlchemy                1.3.24`.

this is my code for getting the resultset and execution the qry:

```
    result = self.connection.execute(qry,multi=True).fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Has anyone a idea?

Comment: You are showing multiple SQL statements. Which one is actually giving this error?

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your code block.

Comment: @GordThompson: Thank you - now I get the results - but there is still a error:
When I run this query in python: I get the results with `.fetchall()` - but these values are not really stored in the table of the database, when I do `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD]` in SSMS the table is still empty.
When I copy the SQL Statement in SSMS and run, with `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD]` I get results?

Comment: @NickW: sorry, I mean I run this all at once.

Comment: Are you using `autocommit=True` or calling `self.connection.commit()` ?

Comment: I was using `self.connection.execute(qry,multi=True).fetchall()`.
Now I added at init of my class `self.connection.execution_options(autocommit=True)`
But now I get the error: `Error occurred during insert: Not an executable object: <class 'flashapi.models.qry'>`